# ACF - How to get custom taxonomy term image field

Tags: custom-taxonomy, loop, advanced-custom-fields

I have loop that displays only the direct children of a term on a taxonomy page. I also have image field, attached to custom taxonomy. Now, I want to display image in my page template:

```
<?php
  $current_term_id = get_queried_object_id();
    $taxonomyName = "car-brand";
    //Could use ACF or basic custom field to get the "parent tax ID" dynamically from a page. At least that's what I would do.
    $parent_tax_ID = $current_term_id;
    $parent_tax = get_term($parent_tax_ID);

    echo '<ul>';
    $terms = get_terms( $taxonomyName, array( 'parent' => $parent_tax_ID, 'orderby' => 'slug', 'hide_empty' => false ) );
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        echo '
        <div class="am-ts-item">
          <a href="' . get_term_link( $term ) . '">
              <div class="am-ts-img">
              <img src=""> 
                  <span>2004 - 2007</span>
              </div>
              <div class="am-ts-info">
                  <h2>' . $term->name . '</h2>
              </div>
          </a>
        </div>
        ';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
?>
```

My image field: "am-brand-img"

Comment: Can you please add details how are you adding image to taxonomy?

Comment: @Pratikbhatt I crated a new ACF group and I added role to brand taxonomy. Now I have a image custom filed in my taxonomy edit page.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this:

```
<?php
    $current_term_id = get_queried_object_id();
    $taxonomyName = "car-brand";
    $parent_tax_ID = $current_term_id;
    $parent_tax = get_term($parent_tax_ID);
    $terms = get_terms( $taxonomyName, array( 'parent' => $parent_tax_ID, 'orderby' => 'slug', 'hide_empty' => false ) );
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
      $image2 = get_field('am-brand-img', $term);
        echo '
        <div class="am-ts-item">
          <a href="' . get_term_link( $term ) . '">
              <div class="am-ts-img">
              <img src="'.$image2['url'].'" alt="'.$image2['alt'].'" />
                  <span>2004 - 2007</span>
              </div>
              <div class="am-ts-info">
                  <h2>' . $term->name . '</h2>
              </div>
          </a>
        </div>
        ';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Get the ACF value from a custom taxonomy.

When retrieving custom fields from taxonomy instead of directly supplying the term ID, you need to concatenate the taxonomy name and the term ID separated by underscore; i.e. `car-brand_4`

```
$taxonomy_id = "car-brand_4"; // 'car-brand' (custom taxonomy) sample term ID = 4

$image = get_field( 'am-brand-img', $taxonomy_id );
```

---

## Get a value from different objects

This example shows a variety of $post_id values to get a value from a post, user, term and option.

```
$post_id = false; // current post
$post_id = 1; // post ID = 1
$post_id = "user_2"; // user ID = 2
$post_id = "category_3"; // category term ID = 3
$post_id = "event_4"; // event (custom taxonomy) term ID = 4
$post_id = "option"; // options page
$post_id = "options"; // same as above

$value = get_field( 'my_field', $post_id );
```

See [`get_field`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/#get-a-value-from-different-objects)